# Работа с выделенным текстом

Tags: python, windows, select

**В наличии:**

1) Windows 10;

2) Python 3;

3) Окно `tkinter`;

4) Форма для работы с текстом, например, `Entry()` или `Text()`;

5) В форме имеется некоторый текст, часть его выделена.

**Задача:** некоторым образом обработать выделенную часть текста.

Например, есть текст: "Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю."

Выделяем курсором мыши некоторую часть текста, например: `мягких французских булок`, затем нажимаем клавишу ESC и этому выделенному тексту присваивается некоторая переменная.

Поиск привел меня к **[этому](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332954/how-to-get-selected-text-with-xsel-python)**, но, на сколько я понял, это решение для Linux, а мне нужно для Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: print(entry.selection_get()))
entry.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Благодарю! То что надо!